# Error in React using react-export-excel after migrating to vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am using react-export-excel to export data to excel. The following error now appears after migrating to vite instead of cra scripts.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cptable is not defined
    at make_xlsx (xlsx.js:10:37)
    at node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js (xlsx.js:12577:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=e898122b:19:50)
    at node_modules/react-export-excel/dist/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js (ExcelFile.js:19:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=e898122b:19:50)
    at node_modules/react-export-excel/dist/index.js (index.js:7:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=e898122b:19:50)
    at index.js:34:1
```

It was working just fine before and iam not quite sure what has happened here.

Update: [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-vite-forked-1pbcg2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A17%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A13%2C%22startColumn%22%3A17%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A13%7D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using react-export-excel to export data to Excel. Mine also appeared after migrating to Vite.